# Trouble with addChild/removeChild and display list order in ActionScript3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am working on a project, which includes a Lake symbol that the player can throw stones into, which in turn causes octopi to rise out of the lake in the positions that each stone hits the lake.

There is also a symbol for the splash made by the stone which will appear after the stone hits and before the octopus appears.

It is likely that there will be many octopi on the screen at the same time and they need to be ordered in the display list so that the ones that should appear further back are behind the others.

Each instance of these symbols should only play once and then be removed.

My code for this makes use of the different add/remove child method alongside for loops, conditionals and arrays which I have put together with the help of various tutorials and forums.

The problem I have is that when you click on the lake two or more times in quick succession, the stone and the splash symbols aren't removed properly and often keep looping.

Here is the code I am using.  Any ideas?

```
var stone:Stone;
var stoneSplash:StoneSplash;
var octopus1:Octopus1;
var octopus2:Octopus2;
var whichOctopus:Array = [addOctopus1, addOctopus2];
var octopusScale:Number;
var octopusContainer:MovieClip = new MovieClip;

lake.lakeHitArea.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickLake);

//Add octopusContainer to the stage's display list just above the Lake
addChildAt(octopusContainer,getChildIndex(lake) + 1);
octopusContainer.x = 0;
octopusContainer.y = 0;

function onClickLake(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace("CLICK");
    throwStone(mouseX, mouseY);
}
function throwStone(stonePositionX:int, stonePositionY:int)
{
    stone = new Stone();
    stone.x = stonePositionX;
    stone.y = stonePositionY;
    addChild(stone);
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, removeStone);
}
function removeStone(e:Event):void
{
    var count:int = numChildren;
    var children:Array = [count];

    //load all the children of the component into an Array
    for (var i:int=0; i<count/* -1*/; i++)
    {
        children[i] = getChildAt(i/* + 1*/);
    }

    for (i=0; i<count/* - 1*/; i++)
    {
        if (children[i] is Stone)
        {
            if (children[i].currentFrameLabel == "Splash")
            {
                stoneSplash = new StoneSplash();
                octopusContainer.addChild(stoneSplash);
                stoneSplash.x = children[i].x;
                stoneSplash.y = children[i].y;
            }
            if (children[i].currentFrameLabel == "end")
            {
                octopusContainer.removeChild(stoneSplash);
                var positionX:int = children[i].x;
                var positionY:int = children[i].y;
                addOctopus(positionX, positionY);
                removeChild(children[i]);
            }
        }
    } 
}
function addOctopus(positionX, positionY)
{
    var o:int = Math.round(randomNumber(0,1));
    whichOctopus[o](positionX, positionY);   
    reorderDisplayList();
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, removeOctopus);
}
function addOctopus1(positionX: int, positionY:int):void
{
//  if (whichOctopus1 == true)
//  {
//      var octopus:* = octopus1_1;
//  }
//  else
//  {
//      octopus = octopus1_2;
//  }
    octopus1 = new Octopus1();
    var octopus:DisplayObject = octopus1;
    octopusContainer.addChild(octopus);
    octopus.x = positionX;
    octopus.y = positionY;
    octopusScale = randomNumber(0.5,0.85);
    octopus.scaleX = octopusScale;
    octopus.scaleY = octopusScale;
    trace("children = " + octopusContainer.numChildren);
    testPosition(octopus);
}
function addOctopus2(positionX: int, positionY:int):void
{
//  if (whichOctopus2 == true)
//  {
//      var octopus:* = octopus2_1;
//  }
//  else
//  {
//      octopus = octopus2_2;
//  }
    octopus2 = new Octopus2();
    var octopus:DisplayObject = octopus2;
    octopusContainer.addChild(octopus);
    octopus.x = positionX;
    octopus.y = positionY;
    octopusScale = randomNumber(0.25,0.5);
    octopus.scaleX = octopusScale;
    octopus.scaleY = octopusScale;
    trace("children = " + octopusContainer.numChildren);
    testPosition(octopus);
}
function testPosition(octopus:Object):void
{
    trace(octopus)
    for (var i:int = 0; i < 200; i++)
    {
        if (lake.hitTestPoint(octopus.x + octopus.hitTestBox1.x * octopus.scaleX,octopus.y + octopus.hitTestBox1.y * octopus.scaleY,true))
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            octopus.x++;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        if (lake.hitTestPoint(octopus.x + octopus.hitTestBox2.x * octopus.scaleX,octopus.y + octopus.hitTestBox2.y * octopus.scaleY,true))
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            octopus.y--;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 200; i++)
    {
        if (lake.hitTestPoint(octopus.x + octopus.hitTestBox3.x * octopus.scaleX,octopus.y + octopus.hitTestBox3.y * octopus.scaleY,true))
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            trace(i);
            octopus.x--;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        if (lake.hitTestPoint(octopus.x + octopus.hitTestBox1.x * octopus.scaleX,octopus.y + octopus.hitTestBox1.y * octopus.scaleY,true))
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            octopus.y--;
            trace(i);
        }
    }
}
function randomNumber(min:Number, max:Number):Number
{
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
function reorderDisplayList():void
{
    //the number of children in our component
    var count:int = octopusContainer.numChildren;
    var children:Array = [count];

    //load all the children of the component into an Array
    for (var i:int=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        children[i] = octopusContainer.getChildAt(i);
    }

    //sort the Array children based on their 'y' property
    children.sortOn("y", Array.NUMERIC);
    //re-add the children to the component ;
    //in the order of the sorted Array we just created.
    //When we add the children using 'addChild' it will 
    //be added at the top of the component's displaylist
    //and will automatically be removed from its original position.
    for (i=0; i<count/* - 1*/; i++)
    {
        if (children[i] is Octopus1 || children[i] is Octopus2)
        {
//          trace("child = " + children[i] + " at i: " + i);
            octopusContainer.removeChild(children[i]);
            octopusContainer.addChild(children[i]);
        }
    } 
}
function removeOctopus(e:Event):void
{
    var count:int = octopusContainer.numChildren;
    var children:Array = [count];

    //load all the children of the component into an Array
    for (var i:int=0; i<count/* -1*/; i++)
    {
        children[i] = octopusContainer.getChildAt(i/* + 1*/);
    }

    for (i=0; i<count/* - 1*/; i++)
    {
        if (children[i] is Octopus1 || children[i] is Octopus2)
        {
            trace(i);
            trace("Is an octopus");
            if (children[i].currentFrame >= 202)
            {
                octopusContainer.removeChild(children[i]);
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

I would greatly appreciate any advice to help me overcome this hurdle and continue with my project.

Thank you in advance.

Chris Collins.

Comment: First glance, you're adding a frame listener every click and not necessarily removing said listener before the next click:  `addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, removeStone);` - chances are most of your issues stem from that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue (or at least one of them) is that your code will only remove the most recent `StoneSplash`.  So if you click a bunch of times in between the splash and end animation , only the last clicked one will get removed.

This is because you are using a global var (`stoneSplash`) to reference the splash, and it gets overwritten to the new one.   You need to either add a splash reference on the stone itself, or create a dictionary so you know which splash goes with which stone.

Here would be one way:

```
if (children[i].currentFrameLabel == "Splash")
        {
            stoneSplash = new StoneSplash(); 
            MovieClop(children[i]).stoneSplash = stoneSplash; //add a reference the splash on the stone itself
```

Then later, instead of `octopusContainer.removeChild(stoneSplash);` do:

```
octopusContainer.removeChild(MovieClop(children[i]).stoneSplash);
```

This way your removing the correct splash that goes with this stone.

---

Here would be a much cleaner way to architect this instead of using an enter frame handler:

1. On your `Stone` class timeline, put the following code on your Splash and End frames respectively:

   Splash frame: `this.dispatchEvent(new Event("Splash"));`

   End frame:    `this.dispatchEvent(new Event("End"));`
2. Listen for those events when you create a new stone instance:

   ```
   stone = new Stone();
   stone.x = stonePositionX;
   stone.y = stonePositionY;
   stone.addEventListener("Splash", splashHandler,false,0,true);
   stone.addEventListener("End",removeStone,false,0,true);
   addChild(stone);
   ```
3. Respond to those events appropriately:

   ```
   function splashHandler(e:Event):void {
       var stone:Stone = e.currentTarget as Stone;
       stoneSplash = new StoneSplash();

       //you need a reference to the splash from the stone class - it would be best to create a class file and add a public property called splashObj and then just use stone.splashObj = new StoneSplash();
       MovieClip(stone).stoneSplash = stoneSplash;  //so on the end event we can read this var to remove stoneSplash
       octopusContainer.addChild(stoneSplash);
       stoneSplash.x = stone.x;
       stoneSplash.y = stone.y;
   }  

   function removeStone(e:Event):void {
       var stone:Stone = e.currentTarget as Stone;
       octopusContainer.removeChild(MovieClip(stone).stoneSplash);
       addOctopus(stone.x, stone.y);
       removeChild(stone);
   }
   ```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the help.  When you say to put the code at the Splash and End frames, do you mean on the symbol editor timeline, or using some as3 code to access the frames? I don't want to put any code directly on the symbols timeline in the symbol editor.

Comment: I mean on the movie clip timeline on the same frame where you have the "Splash" label, put the code there on that frame.  If using timeline animations that need to be synchronized with code, this is by far the most elegant way.

Comment: I tried what you suggested in the first part of your answer and it worked how I want.  Thank you so much for your help.